# Radio Button OnCheckedChanged Not Firing Twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button

There is a radio button inside of a item template of a list view. I had some issues with the list view messing with the group name attribute and used a custom radio button to overcome this (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7960/How-to-group-RadioButtons).

When I click a radio button the event fires correctly. When I click a radio button *after* that the event still only fires once, but it should be firing twice.

I've looked at the source, it appears each control is getting postback event assigned.

```
<tr>
                                    <td class="name">
                                        <span id="cph1_lvOptions_lvGuideSpecOptionGroupOptions_21_lblOptionName_0">None</span>


                                    </td>
                                    <td class="available">

                                    </td>
                                    <td class="available">
                                        <input id="cph1_lvOptions_lvGuideSpecOptionGroupOptions_21_rbOption_0" type="radio" value="ctl00$cph1$lvOptions$ctrl21$lvGuideSpecOptionGroupOptions$ctrl0$rbOption" onclick="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$cph1$lvOptions$ctrl21$lvGuideSpecOptionGroupOptions$ctrl0$rbOption\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" name="Paralleling Switchgear" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td class="name">
                                        <span id="cph1_lvOptions_lvGuideSpecOptionGroupOptions_21_lblOptionName_1">EGP UL 891</span>


                                    </td>
                                    <td class="available">

                                    </td>
                                    <td class="available">
                                        <input id="cph1_lvOptions_lvGuideSpecOptionGroupOptions_21_rbOption_1" type="radio" value="ctl00$cph1$lvOptions$ctrl21$lvGuideSpecOptionGroupOptions$ctrl1$rbOption" onclick="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$cph1$lvOptions$ctrl21$lvGuideSpecOptionGroupOptions$ctrl1$rbOption\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" name="Paralleling Switchgear" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
```

any ideas about what could be causing this? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Each radio button is individually causing a postback (i.e. the page is reloading from the server). The events *should* only be firing one time per postback (per click of a radio button). Clicking one radio button shouldn't cause two events to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the generated javascript, you'll see that the post back happens in the onclick event. The onclick event is only fired for the radio button which you're actually clicking on, not the button which is losing the focus.

Really, I think this is the behavior you want. Otherwise, you'll have to have two round-trips to the server every time the radio button option is changed, which would make your page painfully unresponsive. In your event handler, just check what the new checked radio button is, instead of relying on a second postback.